# "If statement" continuously checking for multiples of for loop's index count

Tags: java, if-statement, console

I have a for loop that checks for every 5th position. And at every 5th position, I'm performing an action like so (which works):

```
for(int i = 0; i < foo().length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(i);

    if(i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Is there a way to write if statement so no matter how long `foo().length` is, I don't have to keep coming back to adjust it?

Comment: what do you mean by coming back and adjusting it?

Answer (score 8):

Use `modulus(%)` operator: -

```
if (i % 5 == 0) {

}
```

- `5 % 5 == 0`, `10 % 5 == 0`, ...

---

Since you are using a `for loop`, you can simply change your increment from `i++` to `i += 5`, and leave the if condition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < someNum; i += 5) {
    // No need to check for `i` against `modulus 5`.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use next `for` witout `if` statement

```
for(int i = 0; i < foo().length; i+=5)
{
```

adding `5` to `i` step by step

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
if ( i % 5 == 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put it in a single print statement this would work too.

```
for(int i = 0; i < foo().length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%d%s", i, (i%5==0) ? "\n" : "");
}
```